# SKShapeNode not working on IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

```
gameOverBox = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithRectOfSize:CGSizeMake(self.size.width-80, self.size.height/2-100)];
gameOverBox.fillColor = [SKColor yellowColor];
gameOverBox.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/4);
[self addChild:gameOverBox];
```

I was trying to run a game I made on IOS 8, it works with 0 error.
But after trying to run this on an IOS 7 device, simulator or an actual device, the app still crashed. The debugger said that the first line was causing this problem.
But why is the first line causing the error?

The error is `[SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithRectOfSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to class`

Comment: That method is iOS 8 only, if you just need a colored rectangle, you could use `- (instancetype)initWithColor:(SKColor *)color size:(CGSize)size` method of SKSpriteNode.

Answer (score 6):

This functionality is not available in iOS 7. It is only iOS 8 and later.

[SKShapeNode Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKShapeNode/shapeNodeWithRectOfSize%3a)